# Python logging-module that writes to both the console and a file

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, reinventing-the-wheel, logging

I've created a small module with a function `plog()` that allows to easily print to both a log file and the console. It also creates a directory "log" at the location of the file that imports the module. Although I'm quite a beginner in terms of Python I'm not satisfied with my code since I'm using two global variables. I need those, because they store the name of the last file and function that called `plog()`. So could you guys give me recommendations how I could improve the code and make it more 'pythonic'? This is my code so far:

```py
import datetime
import inspect
import os

print("Setting up logfile via very_nice_log.py")

# create name of log file via datetime
log_file_name = str(datetime.datetime.now())[:-9]
log_file_name = log_file_name.replace("-", "")
log_file_name = log_file_name.replace(" ", "")
log_file_name = log_file_name.replace(":", "")

# check if it is possible to get the path of the file that called very_nice_log
if len(inspect.stack()[1:]) == 0:
    print("WARNING: could not locate file that called very_nice_log")

# get path of the file that imported very_nice_log
for frame in inspect.stack()[1:]:
    if frame.filename[0] != '<':
        log_path = "/".join(frame.filename.split("/")[:-1])
        print("Log path is " + log_path)
        break

log_path = log_path + "/log"

# check if there is a directory called "log", create one if not
if not os.path.isdir(log_path):
    os.mkdir(log_path)

# create log file
print(log_path + "/" + log_file_name + ".txt")
log_file = open(log_path + "/" + log_file_name + ".txt", "w+")

print("Created log file")

log_file.write("Starting to log...\n\n")

# set up 2 variables to store the last function and file that called plog()
last_func_name = ""
last_module_name = ""


# define a function that prints to both the log file and the console
def plog(amk):
    # set those variables to global to store the names of the last file and function
    global last_func_name
    global last_module_name

    # print the string to console
    print(amk)

    # get the name and function that called plog()
    module_name = (inspect.stack()[1][1].split("/")[-1])[:-3]
    func_name = inspect.stack()[1][3]

    # if plog is not called from a function, set function name to "main"
    if func_name == "<module>":
        func_name = "main"

    # if file or function has changed since last time plog got called, write a seperator
    if module_name != last_module_name:
        log_file.write("=====================================================================\n")
    elif func_name != last_func_name:
        log_file.write("---------------------------\n")

    # write to log file
    log_file.write(str(datetime.datetime.now())[:-7] + ": " + module_name + ": " + func_name + ": " + amk + "\n")

    # update the names of last file and function
    last_func_name = func_name
    last_module_name = module_name
```

edit: Usage
Simply write

```py
from very_nice_log import plog
plog("foo")
```

in another python file.

This is an example output to the log file. 2 files hello.py and testing2.py were used:

```
Starting to log...

=====================================================================
2019-06-09 16:51:02: hello: main: Amk1
2019-06-09 16:51:02: hello: main: amk2
---------------------------
2019-06-09 16:51:02: hello: func1: func1mak
2019-06-09 16:51:02: hello: func1: func1mak
---------------------------
2019-06-09 16:51:02: hello: func2: func2amk
---------------------------
2019-06-09 16:51:02: hello: func1: func1mak
=====================================================================
2019-06-09 16:51:02: testing2: func45: amkanderesfile
2019-06-09 16:51:02: testing2: func45: amkanderesfile
=====================================================================
2019-06-09 16:51:02: hello: func1: func1mak
=====================================================================
2019-06-09 16:51:02: testing2: func45: amkanderesfile
---------------------------
2019-06-09 16:51:02: testing2: func46: yoyoyo
2019-06-09 16:51:02: testing2: func46: yoyoyo
---------------------------
2019-06-09 16:51:02: testing2: func45: amkanderesfile
```

As you can see it nicely separates the log-file into section between different files and functions. I'm very happy with this but as I said, I'm a bit concerned about the quality of my code. Especially the global variables seem to be a bad solution. So what would you guys change and why? I am very curious about your suggestions and would love to learn how to write better code.

Best,
Tobi

Comment: Idk about you...but the code already seems beautiful...I was just searching for a logger...more than happy to find one...the output looks pretty neat...thanks

Comment: Do you know about the `logging` library? If you don't want an answer to be "Try using`logging`" you should tag this with [tag:reinventing-the-wheel].

Comment: @Peilonrayz alright, I've added the tag. I know about the logging-library but to be honest I preferred to write my own code instead of trying to understand the library

Comment: Generally when I write a custom logger, I will use a decorator. These are great because they just wrap around any function/method call and can tell you about state; capture errors; print to files etc. There will also be ways around using globals by capturing what you need from the function you're decorating.

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions:

- You could use `str(datetime.date.today())` to get the current date.
- You can chain `replace` calls:

  ```
  >>> 'abba'.replace('a', 'c').replace('b', 'd')
  'cddc'
  ```
- `if len(inspect.stack()[1:]) == 0:` would usually be replaced with just `if inspect.stack()[1:]`.
- Treating your variables as immutable makes the code much easier to read. For example, `log_path = "/".join(frame.filename.split("/")[:-1]) + "/log"` means you only have to understand one assignment rather than the connection between two of them.
- `os.makedirs` takes [an option so you don't have to check whether the directory exists already](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?highlight=makedirs#os.makedirs).
- String concatenation using `+` is discouraged for anything more than two strings. Probably the best solution available today is [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings). For example, `log_path + "/" + log_file_name + ".txt"` would become `f"{log_path}/{log_file_name}.txt"`.
- I don't understand the name `amk`. Names are incredibly important for the maintainability of your code, but I don't know what to suggest as a replacement except possibly `message`.
- You could put the globals into fields in a class; that way they would be kept between invocations without polluting the main namespace.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on l0b0's answer:

- Don't chain `str.replace`'s for the same reason you don't concatenate strings. If you need to perform multiple translations at the same time instead use `str.maketrans` and `str.translate`.

  ```
  >>> table = str.maketrans('ab', 'cd', 'e')
  >>> 'abeeba'.translate(table)
  'cddc'
  ```
- Your code only supports Unix paths, this means it doesn't work on Windows. To fix this change all of your `'/'` to `os.sep`.
- Rather than manual string file handling, you should use [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html).

  ```
  # From
  "/".join(frame.filename.split("/")[:-1])
  logpath + os.sep + "log"

  # To
  pathlib.Path(frame.filename).parent
  logpath / "log"
  ```
- Add some more function calls. With good names they should remove your comments.
- You have two quite large bugs with `log_path` generation. Firstly if the `inspect.stack()[1:]` is empty or all the file names start with `'<'` your code results in a `NameError`. The second won't even print the warning.
- If you can't create the log file, you can always default to `os.devnull` or some other reasonable default.

```
import datetime
import inspect
import os
import pathlib

print("Setting up logfile via very_nice_log.py")


def get_datetime_file_name():
    table = str.maketrans(None, None, "- :")
    return (
        str(datetime.datetime.today()).translate(table)
        + '.txt'
    )


def get_log_path():
    for frame in inspect.stack()[1:]:
        if frame.filename[0] != '<':
            return pathlib.Path(frame.filename).parent
    print("WARNING: could not locate file that called very_nice_log")
    return None


def make_log_file():
    log_path = get_log_path()
    if log_path is None:
        return open(os.devnull, "w")
    log_path /= "log"
    log_path.mkdir(parents=True, exists_ok=True)
    log_path /= get_datetime_file_name()
    print(str(log_path))
    return log_path.open("w+")


print("Created log file")
log_file = make_log_file()
log_file.write("Starting to log...\n\n")
```